# Recap API send files from disk

Tags: c#, httprequest, autodesk-forge

I'm trying to replicate in C# the curl request to send files (from disk) to a photoscene using Recap API.

```
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/file' \
-X 'POST' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer eyjhbGCIOIjIuzI1NiISimtpZCI6...' \
-F "photosceneid=hcYJcrnHUsNSPII9glhVe8lRF6lFXs4NHzGqJ3zdWMU" \
-F "type=image" \
-F "file[0]=@c:/sample_data/_MG_9026.jpg" \
-F "file[1]=@c:/sample_data/_MG_9027.jpg"
```

So far I got this in C#

```
private async Task<string> SendUploadJsonAsync(PhotoSceneImages obj, HttpMethod method, string token)
{
    const string url = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/file";

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent
        {
            {new StringContent(obj.photosceneid), "photosceneid"}, {new StringContent("type"), "image"}
        };

        var i = 0;
        foreach (var image in obj.files)
        {
            formData.Add(new ByteArrayContent(image), "file["+ i++ +"]");
        }
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Content = formData,
            Headers =
            {
                Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token)
            },
            Method = method,
            RequestUri = new Uri(url)
        };

        try
        {
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting a not implemented yet reply from the autodesk server.

Don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

The PhotoSceneImages object contains a string with the photosceneid and an array of array of bytes containing the bytes of the image files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working,

```
private async Task<string> SendUploadImagesAsync(PhotoSceneImages obj, HttpMethod method, string token)
{
    const string url = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/file";

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent
        {
            {new StringContent(obj.photosceneid), "photosceneid"}, {new StringContent(obj.type), "type"}
        };

        var i = 0;
        foreach (var file in obj.files)
        {
            formData.Add(new ByteArrayContent(file.byteArray), $"file[{i++}]", file.filename);
        }
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Content = formData,
            Headers =
            {
                Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token)
            },
            Method = method,
            RequestUri = new Uri(url)
        };
        Debug.Log($"request: {request}");
        try
        {
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically two things that were wrong, the field ("type":"image") I was sending it the wrong way around and you also need to send the filename on the formData as a third parameter.